# Chrome error when using opener on pop-up window (cross-origin)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.opener

I have a local website containing pop-up windows that should be able to access their parents.

Those pop-up windows are opened as seen here:

```
open("filename.html", 'name', 'scrollbars=yes,width=700');
```

And I am trying to set them to access their parent window with `window.opener` property.

This works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome, where I get an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I've also noticed that when being uploaded to a server it just works fine on both Chrome and Firefox.

**How can I make this work on Chrome when running on local?** Is there any alternative to `window.opener` that allows the child window to acces their parent?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with a project... My temporal-solution was to set up a local server, for example:

1. Download http-server:

   `$ npm install http-server -g`
2. Look for the project main folder in the console and type:

   `$ http-server`
3. The console will show you in which port you can run your website in local

Now you can use window.opener in Chrome. I'd like to have a better solution!

By the way, another idea is replacing child-windows for modals :)